# If I change to a razor page in my blazor server side app, the page is opening after all the page-related data is processed on the page, why?

Tags: c#, file, blazor-server-side

I have a server side blazor app. In one of the razor pages there is shown the content of a large log text file (2MB with appr. 30000 lines) that is on the same server. The content is refreshed when everytime a button is pressed.

If I press the button for the first time then it takes 4-5 seconds when the text content is shown on the pages table rows, line by line. I don't know if I can shorten this time but let's say this is OK. When I leave the page and click on the page link to come back, the page opens after 4-5 seconds. I assume that this is again the time for showing all lines of the text file on the screen.

1. What I want at least is, that first the page opens immediatly,the loading circle runs and then the page content loads after 4-5 seconds, as usual expected.
2. Is it normal that it takes to read the text file line by line 4-5 seconds? How can I change my code to shorten this time. My target is to show the file content on my razor page.

My razor code:

```
<body>
<table class="page_header">
    <tr class="tr_button_bar">
        <td class="td_button_bar" align="left">
            <button class="button_1"  @onclick="Read_Error_Log"><img class="button_image" src="images/read_data.svg"><br>Error Log</button>           
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>  
<style>
    .preformatted {
        white-space: pre;
        max-width:1600px;           
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 1;
    }
</style>

@if (TagService.Loading_Main_Log == true)
{
    <div class="spinner"></div>
}

<table class="log_file_table">

    @for (int f = 0; f < TagService.Error_log.Count; f++)
    {
        <tr style="max-height:20px !important">
            <td class=".log_file"><pre class="preformatted">@TagService.Error_log[f]</pre></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
</body>
```

My razor.cs code

```
public partial class Logs
{
    public async Task Read_Error_Log()
    {
        TagService.Loading_Main_Log = true;
        await Task.Delay(1);
        try
        {
            TagService.Error_log.Clear();
                Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
                var lines = File.ReadLines(CommonClass.error_path, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1254"));
                var line_trimmed = "";

                foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    TagService.Error_log.Add(line);
                }               
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(CommonClass.error_path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Read_Error_Log() Error " + e + " " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
            }
        }
        TagService.Loading_Main_Log = false;
    }        
}
```

My Navigation code to the page

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" href="logs" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
<span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Error Log
```

Comment: @jeb Don't agree with you. I use Blazor server side (not webassembly) app, and the razor.cs code is processed always on the server side, not on the client side. Additionally I do the tests always from another machines's browser, not directly on the server. Who said that I am working on the server?

Comment: I was somehow sure I was reading blazor wasm. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

30.000 lines: seems like an awfully large amount of lines, and probably a large part being useless for the user.

You should use paging, or load on the fly when scrolling down or any other UI/UX allowing navigation through the lines of your file, to reduce loading time and ease it for users.

If you want to be sure to first load the page and then show the data, wrap your table lines with a local variable (a boolean for instance) that you set when the page is displayed.